# Changing BaseURI of OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter not Redirecting Properly

Tags: spring-security, spring-rest, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to get the `baseUri` of the `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter` to redirect properly with a github-specific oauth chain but I can't seem to figure it out. My setup of the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` has the `ClientRegistrationRepository` set and I'm using the following to set the base-uri:

```
.authorizationEndpoint()
.baseUri(GitHubRequestPaths.GITHUB_OAUTH_REDIRECT)
//Note the above is defined as:
//String GITHUB_OAUTH_REDIRECT = "/github/oauth2/authorization"
```

But Spring seems to be complaining that it can't match the authorization endpoint which I believe is making it so it doesn't correctly redirect to the github login for the `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter`. I'm seeing the following in the debug which is what is leading me to that idea:

```
2021-12-07 10:20:24.015 DEBUG 11283 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /github/oauth2/authorization at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter'
2021-12-07 10:20:24.015 DEBUG 11283 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/github/oauth2/authorization'; against '/github/oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}'
2021-12-07 10:20:24.015 DEBUG 11283 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /github/login at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter'
2021-12-07 10:20:24.015 DEBUG 11283 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/github/login'; against '/login/oauth2/code/*'
2021-12-07 10:20:24.015 DEBUG 11283 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /github/login at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2021-12-07 10:20:24.015 DEBUG 11283 --- [nio-8091-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
```

The way the web page is set up is that it gathers the login from a base directory call which returns the GitHub login as what I've set the authorization login call to be (`/github/oauth2/authorization`). I've tried manually setting the registration id (`/github/oauth2/authorization/GitHub`) but Spring just returns a similar error of looking for a match to `/github/oauth2/authorization/GitHub/{registrationId}`. It seems to try to match to `baseUri + /{registrationId}`, can I edit this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get around this by creating my own `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` which almost exactly mirrored `DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` but with the registration id's hardcoded.